# unwanted space between image and paragraph

Tags: html, css

[image]

There is an unwanted space with adding this tag : `<span class="prname">f</span>`
I wnat to stick `img` tag with `<p id="id">df</p>` tag without that white space,and then `<span class="prname">f</span>` tag should be inside the image.
How can i do that?

```css
.card {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 44px  ;
    max-width: 400px;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: arial;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 6px;
    position: relative;
    top: 111px;
}

.card img {
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.prname {
    background-color: #2196F3;
    font-size: 22px;
    border-radius: 11px;
    color: white;
    padding: 3px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 1px;
}

#id {
    background-color: palevioletred;
    color: white;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 17px;
}
```

```html
<body>
     
        <div class="card">
            
            <img src="https://pixelmechanics.com.sg/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/html5-logo-for-web-development.png"> 
                    

      <span class="prname">f</span>
            
            <p id="id">df</p>
            
        </div>
    
</body>
```

Comment: By "inside the image", do you mean that the HTML5 image and `span` tag with "f" as its content should be overlapping?

Comment: absolute position your span tag